# Performance : Checked and unchecked exceptions in JAVA

Tags: java, c#, performance, exception

I know the advantage of checked exceptions: Force developers to declare all exceptions thrown by their functions.

But I was wondering:

-Do checked exceptions affect the performance positively?

-If so, Is a C# program slower than JAVA in case of exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checked exceptions only have restrictions at compile time. At runtime, all types of exceptions behave the same way.

Comment: Just waiting for other answers before flagging yours as the correct one.

Comment: What do you think of this :http://learnwithharsha.com/exceptions/

"The exceptions that are checked by the compiler for smooth execution of program are know as Checked Exception. We should handle checked exceptions in our program to compile."

Comment: @Jonas Do you mean in regards to _smooth execution_? I would assume they mean so that you don't get a surprise from an unchecked exception popping your entire stack.

Comment: I thought that checked exceptions where handled at compile time so that at runtime it would pop up faster to the catch block

Comment: @Jonas No, there is no difference at runtime.